# Why isn't Aryabhata more famous than Pythagoras?

Tags: mathematicians

You saw the question right. Why isn't it so? [Aryabhata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryabhata#Mathematics) had done more things than him. Is it because of the 400 or 500 years of difference between their existence? [Pythagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras#Mathematics) is famous most for his just one theorem. Is there something about Pythagoras that I don't know?

Comment: It seems there is something about Pythagoras that you don't know.  See http://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/391/229 ... In fact, almost all mathematicians did more mathematics than Pythagoras.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar ok I get it what u r saying and thanks for that information. But there still is the question. "Why is Aryabhata not well known?"

Comment: @manshu: Aryabhata is sufficiently well known to historians of mathematics. Pythagoras is known to much broader public because he or his school stand at the very beginning of mathematics and of modern science in general.

Comment: Mathematics of proofs and rigor is usually traced to Greeks, specifically Thales and Pythagoreans (not Pythagoras himself though, as we now know). Oriental traditions, including Indian and Chinese, developed some very intricate mathematical methods, but overall viewed mathematics in terms of practical recipes for solving particular types of problems. So modern mathematicians feel much more "affinity" to Pythagoreans than to Aryabhata.

Comment: @Conifold So you mean Indian and Chinese mathematician could not offer proofs while Greeks did, that's why Pythagoreans are taken as 'those who put the base of mathematics'. I got it right?

Comment: It's not so much that they could not, it's that their motivation and approach were different. Eventually (last 2-3 centuries) even India and China adopted proof-based approach, so one could say that Greeks "put the base" for modern mathematics.