# Why didn't the ancient Greeks consider 1 to be odd?

Tags: mathematics, ancient-greece, number-theory

The [Wikipedia page on parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)#History) currently says:

> The ancient Greeks considered 1, the monad, to be neither fully odd nor fully even

Why didn't they consider 1 as odd? (I am assuming they already had the concept of odd and even numbers.) What did they consider it as?

Comment: Hello. Perhaps you could look the discussion about the baffling concept of "even-odd"  https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6721/what-are-philolaos-even-odd-numbers

Comment: They (at least Pythagoreans and Euclid) did not consider 1 to be a number either, because [number had to be a *multitude* of units](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7EDJoyce/java/elements/bookVII/bookVII.html#defs). And since an odd had to be the unit attached to an even, and they they did not have zero, the unit by itself did not qualify.

Comment: One is the only integer that's not divisible by other integers but is not a prime number.  That makes it pretty odd, so the Greeks were wrong.   #itsajokedammit

Comment: Some Greek schools of thought were also a bit suspicious of $2$, on the grounds that a number had to have a beginning, a middle and an end, and $2$ lacked a middle.